# How can I use Lighttpd's $HTTP["remoteip"] together with Cloudflare?

Tags: lighttpd, cloudflare

I am using Clodflare DNS. I only want to allow certain IPs to access certain files.

How can I set up my lighttpd.conf to properly detect the correct IP? I know how to do it for the access.log. Is it possible to use  $HTTP["remoteip"] together withsomething else?

This is how I do it today:

```
 $HTTP["remoteip"] == "xx.xx.xx.xx" {
    url.access-deny = ("")
}
```

I have tried with the following but it didnt work:

```
 $HTTP["remoteip"] =="*"{
   extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
   extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$HTTP["remoteip"]` will never equal the string `*`, it will have a value representing the connecting IP address (some Cloudflare address in your case).

Having that condition in place means that the `extforward` settings inside are never applied, which would appear to be your problem.

As for `extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust")`, this may not be a good idea if non-Cloudflare addresses can connect. Allowing anyone to specify the remote address in a header makes any kind of access checks based on IP trivial to circumvent.

Cloudflare do have some [documentation on this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170826-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Lighttpd-) as well.

Comment: I managed to get it to work now. The Cloduflare setting example didnt work 100% for me. I will post my solution once I am able.

Answer (score 0):

The settings from the Cloudflare seem to give errors due to duplicate entries of IPs.

Here is the settings that works for me. I put them after `server.modules { .. }`:

```
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "199.27.128.0/21" {
extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "173.245.48.0/20" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "103.21.244.0/22" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "103.22.200.0/22" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "103.31.4.0/22" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "141.101.64.0/18" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "108.162.192.0/18" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "190.93.240.0/20" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "188.114.96.0/20" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "197.234.240.0/22" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "198.41.128.0/17" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "162.158.0.0/15" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "104.16.0.0/12" {
    extforward.forwarder = ( "all" => "trust" )
    extforward.headers = ("CF-Connecting-IP")
}
```

With this $HTTP["remoteip"] works fine.